# Godel's Second Incompleteness Theorem Proof - Clarification

Tags: logic, incompleteness

My question stems from this post - [Informal proof of Gödel's second incompleteness theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1656193/informal-proof-of-g%c3%b6dels-second-incompleteness-theorem)

Basically the proof of second incompleteness theorem goes like this:

Say G is the Godel statement of T.
Cons(T) => G

So if we manage to prove Cons(T) within T, then we have a contradiction and hence it is inconsistent.

But then we also know that if a system is inconsistent then every statement is provable.
Basically,

$\neg Cons(T) => G$

So if Cons(T) => G and $\neg Cons(T) => G$

then G should be true independent of whether Cons(T) is true.
Why cannot we formalize that argument within T to prove that G is true without asserting Cons(T)?
What am I missing?

Comment: You have to distinguish between what a theory proves and what a theory proves it proves - these don't actually coincide! This is a very good (and common) question, but it is essentially the same issue as in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4179554/puzzle-does-the-following-prove-that-pa-is-inconsistent-part-2) (which phrases it in terms of specifically $T=\mathsf{PA}$).